# EM_JS: How to convert int argc, char **argv to a JS array of strings?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to call JS function from C/C++ with an array of strings as an argument.

Here's my example code:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EM_JS(void, call_myFunc, (int argc, char **argv), {
     
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      arr.push(UTF8ToString(argv[i]));
    }
    myFunc(arr);
});

int main()
{
    int argc = 4;
    char *argv[5] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh" };
    call_myFunc(argc, argv);
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  function myFunc(args) {
    console.log(args);
  }
  </script>
  <script async src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**build:**

```
emcc main.c -o main.html
```

**result I get:**

```
["", "", "", ""]
```

**result I want:**

```
["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
```

How can I properly convert `char **argv` to a JS array of strings?

Comment: I am curious - We can compile C++ code to JS? What is this?

Comment: Look at the main.html how the script invoked and do the same in index.html. No main.wasm is used at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How can I properly convert `char **argv` to a JS array of strings?**

From the documentation of [`emscripten.h`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html):

> Null-terminated C strings can also be passed into `EM_JS` functions, but to operate on them, they need to be copied out from the heap to convert to high-level JavaScript strings.

```
EM_JS(void, say_hello, (const char* str), {
  console.log('hello ' + UTF8ToString(str));
}
```

> In the same manner, pointers to any type (including `void *`) can be passed inside `EM_JS` code, where they appear as integers like `char *` pointers above did. Accessing the data can be managed by reading the heap directly.

```
EM_JS(void, read_data, (int* data), {
  console.log('Data: ' + HEAP32[data>>2] + ', ' + HEAP32[(data+4)>>2]);
});

int main() {
  int arr[2] = { 30, 45 };
  read_data(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

---

So, you can use `HEAP32` along with `UTF8ToString` like this:

**main.c**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EM_JS(void, call_myFunc, (const int argc, const char** argv), {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        const mem = HEAP32[(argv + (i * 4)) >> 2];
        const str = UTF8ToString(mem);
        arr.push(str);
    }
    console.log(arr);
});

int main() {
    const int argc = 4;
    const char* argv[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh" };
    call_myFunc(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```sh
emcc main.c -o main.html
```

Run with `node`:

```sh
node main.js
```

Output:

```sh
[ 'ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh' ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I use this one instead? `EM_JS(void, call_myFunc, (int argc, char **argv), {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      arr.push(UTF8ToString(HEAP32[(argv >> 2) + i]));
    }
    myFunc(arr);
});`

Comment: @ZackLee: You're welcome! Sure, you can combine those statements. Just make sure you adjust the pointer accordingly as you move through the heap i.e. `HEAP32[(argv + (i * 4)) >> 2]`. So, it would be `arr.push(UTF8ToString(HEAP32[(argv + (i * 4)) >> 2]));`.

Comment: @ZackLee: BTW, how are you testing your existing setup? Could you please share a bit about it?

Comment: What do you mean how I test it? I use `python3 -m http.server 8080` to test it in my browser.

Comment: @ZackLee: Alright. Simply, serving the files. Are you doing any performance testing also e.g. calling JS from C/C++ vs embedded JS in C/C++ code?

Comment: No, I haven't done any performance testing yet. Is there a huge difference between the two?

Comment: @ZackLee: It depends on the approach I believe. I strongly believe that the actual measurement reveals more than mere guesses. Here's the relevant article: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code

Comment: I don't understand this statement `HEAP32[(argv + (i * 4)) >> 2]` at all. Why is it multiplying by 4 and doing a right shift of 2? Can someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: @Azeem Hope you're still around. What does 4 actually means here?

Comment: @jeffbRTC: Are you referring to 4 in this `HEAP32[(argv + (i * 4)) >> 2];`?

Comment: @jeffbRTC: I believe that it's like this: item 0 = `HEAP32[(ptr + 0) >> 2]`, item 1 = `HEAP32[(ptr + 4) >> 2]`, item 2 = `HEAP32[(ptr + 8) >> 2]`, and so on. See docs for more details: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html. There's no explanation in the docs about the right shift, though.

Comment: @Azeem But how come I see the value without 4? Here, I see value without doing that 4 thing..

Comment: @jeffbRTC: Can you show the statement and value you're observing?

Comment: @Azeem This neatly `HEAP32[(argv + i) >> 2]`  prints all items on this array, `[ 'ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh' ]`

Comment: @jeffbRTC: That's strange. I remember that I had to use that exact expression mentioned in their docs to prints the values. It's best to ask by opening an issue directly on the repo (https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/new/choose). Let me know how that goes. I'd also be interested to understand this change.